# Cannot install Tensorflow with Pycharm because of Protobuf error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I installed Pycharm for Windows 10

`pip install tensorflow` went fine without errors

When trying to run a simple project

```
    # Import `tensorflow`
import tensorflow as tf

# Initialize two constants
x1 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4])
x2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8])

# Multiply
result = tf.multiply(x1, x2)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//PycharmProjects/RiffRam/RiffRam.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\RiffRam\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\RiffRam\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\RiffRam\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\RiffRam\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Can somebody please tell me how I can get a working installation of Tensorflow, it seems that all the versions are mismatched and pip makes no attempt to install correct versions of each package. I don't care if its outdated.

What commands do I need to type in to get a working stable version from a clean installation of Pycharm so that the code above would run?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, I haven't dealt with this problem specific to tensorflow, but in other packages, where DLL files failed to load properly, installing dependencies using precompiled binaries can solve the problem. You can get most of them here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools==39.1.0
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall protobuf==3.6.0
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow==1.11
```